# How to Add/Remove class jQuery in filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have filter on my website. There are categories and it display services from category when you click on that category link. 
I want to add animation for those posts, so when I click on category to animate those posts. I made animation and all I need is to add fade-in-services class to every post when I click on his category, and before that to remove if that post have fade-in-services class.

I have two lists, one for categories, other for posts and that looks like this

```
<ul class="subcats">
<li>
  <a href="#">All</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Cat1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Cat2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="posts">
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="fade-in-services">Post 1</div>
  </a></li>
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="fade-in-services">Post 2</div>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="fade-in-services">Post 3</div>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

So when you click on All it displays all three posts, when click on Cat1 displays only Post 1 and Post 2, and when you click on Cat2 displays Post 3.

```
jQuery('.subcats li').click(function() {                            
    jQuery('.hp-single-service').addClass('fade-in-services');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('fade-in-services');
    });
```

and this work but not always, because `jQuery(this) catch .subcats li` and doesn't remove class `fade-in-services`. So when I go throw categories, if same post is in two categories that post doesn't animate because it have `fade-in-service` class.

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your code does what you think it does. It does the following:

1. Sets an on click event on the 3 `li` in the `ul.subcats`
2. When one of the `li` is clicked it:

   2a. Adds `.fade-in-services` to all elements with `.hp-single-service`

   2b. Removes `.fade-in-services` from the clicked `li`

   2bi. (which doesn't have the class at any point)

Comment: I know what my code works, it works like you described, and I don't want to it works like that, so I asked question to someone help me how to change it to remove class .fade-in-services from .hp-single-service, and I know that  this row jQuery(this).removeClass('fade-in-services'); doesn't work that, so I'm asking how to change to work like that?